# Consulta en Firebase Database, qué tipo de dato retorna un campo con varios objetos?

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Estoy tratando de obtener unos valores de Realtime Database, en un campo que tengo de clientes; llamado imágenes, se almacenan varios objetos...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando obtener esos objetos para obtener sus datos, no encuentro el tipo de dato para hacer el cast, siempre me arroja "nil" ya estuve buscando en stackoverflow y otras fuentes pero hasta el momento no he podido adaptar alguna solución.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
    handle = ref.child("Clientes").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.listaClientes.removeAll()
        for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            let valores = item.value as? [String:AnyObject]



            let email = valores!["email"] as? String
            let estado = valores!["estado"] as? String
            let id = valores!["id"] as? String
            let mes = valores!["mes"]
            let nombre = valores!["nombre"] as? String
            let pais = valores!["pais"] as? String

            let imagenes = valores!["imagenes"] as?


        }
    })
```

cuál sería el tipo de dato correcto para hacer el cast o debo hacer algo más?

Answer (score 0):

ahi en la base de datos te dice que los tipos de datos son los siguientes

```
id = string
estado = string 
email = string
fecha = string
publicada = boolean
publicar = boolean
ruta = string
sucursal = string
```

esta linea

```
let imagenes = valores!["imagenes"] as?
```

no te hace falta si estas iterando adentro de todo el nodo `clientes`

podes seguir haciendo como los de arriba para obtener los datos adentro de cada push

por ejemplo

```
let fecha = valores!["fecha"] as? String
let publicada = valores!["publicada"] as? boolean
let publicar = valores!["publicar"] as? boolean
let ruta = valores!["ruta"] as? String
let sucursal = valores!["sucursal"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo como esto:

```
for item in snapShot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
 //aqui tu código para obtener el email, etc.
    let imagenes = item.childSnapshot(forPath:"imagenes").children.allObjects
        .map({$0 as? DataSnapshot})
        .map({$0?.value as? [String: Any]})
        .compactMap({$0})
       //array de dictionary 
       print(imagenes)
       imagenes.forEach({ (dictionary) in
          let fecha = dictionary["fecha"] as? String
          let ruta = dictionary["ruta"] as? String
          print(fecha ?? "")
          print(ruta ?? "")
       })
}
```

Espero te sirva, use un poco de programación funcional para evitar poner mucho código, de hecho se puede reducir aun más pero te voy a revolver.